# Linear Algebra: Identity map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification

I was asked to prove that the identity map $id : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^n $ can be represented by the the identity matrix regardless of the basis

**My Attempt:**

Let $\mathcal B  = \lbrace v_1 , ...,v_n \rbrace $ be a basis for $\Bbb R^n$.
The image under $id$ of each element in $\mathcal B$ can be expressed as follows

$id(v_1 ) = 1v_1 + 0 v_2 +...
+ 0v_n$

.

.

.

$id(v_n) = 0v_1 + ... +0v_{n-1}+1v_n$

So $id$ can be represented by $I_n$

However, I am not convinced that this a rigorous and complete enough proof.

If not, how would I go about proving this?

Comment: To make it more rigorous you should replace $\vdots$ and $\ldots$ by induction.

Comment: @GitGud Proof by induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Induction is easily avoided.  Suppose that vector $u = \sum_i^n c_i v_i$ has that *unique* representation in terms of *ordered* basis $\mathscr{B}=\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$.  Now $id(u)=u$ has that representation and $I_n (c_1,\ldots,c_n)^T = (c_1,\ldots,c_n)^T$.  Thus $I_n$, the identity matrix, represents $id$, the identity map, with respect to any ordered basis.

Comment: What is with the parenthesis?

Comment: The unique representation being $u = \sum_{i}^n c_i v_i $

Comment: I put parentheses around "unique" and "ordered" because these are points that essentially go without saying.  Of course the fact that $\mathscr{B}$ is a basis means the representation is unique, and to define a matrix representation means the basis needs to have some ordering chosen (so that we know how the coefficients of the representation occur in the column representation of the vector).

Comment: I took the parentheses away.  It should be clear enough without them, though I think I'll use italics for emphasis.